# How can I make the content of listview be horizontally arrange?

Tags: android, listview

What should I use or do in the listview to make its content horizontally arrange? What I'm trying to do with listview is like a normal table table with header, each row is the information about the employee.I will populate the listview with the data from the database but I don't know how to make it that way that all the information of an employee should be in a row. Is it possible?

Comment: Which platform? Many different platforms have something called "listview".

Comment: uh.. i'm sorry i forgot. in android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use 2 webview, one for the header and the other one is for the details,just concatenate the details for each employee. That works for me!

Answer (score 0):

I recently wanted to create a horizontal `ListView` in Android. However, there was no obvious way to implement this. I ended up using a [`Gallery`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html) instead.

Note that the `Gallery` is deprecated in API level 16. The documentation points to a couple of other widgets that offer horizontal scrolling features.